# How can I configure Maven build job on Jenkins to tell SonarQube the build job's URL?

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube

I have a build job on Jenkins which executes Maven tasks. One of the tasks is `sonar:sonar` which makes a static source code analysis on our SonarQube server.

How can I tell Maven in the build job configuration to take the property `sonar.links.ci=%JOB_URL%` which is responsible for displaying the build job's URL on the project's site on SonarQube?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you just pass it as a property to maven task. Dsonar.links.ci=${JOB_URL}
sonar:sonar

Comment: Perfect! I added `-Dsonar.links.ci=${JOB_URL}` to the `sonar:sonar` call and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: @I-LOVE-2-REVIVE I would suggest to move the comment to an answer, so that the question would not be left unanswered and things would be more clear for future visitors.

Comment: well, I also suggest @andreasgk to accept it then :)

Answer (score 2):

You just pass it as a property to maven task. `Dsonar.links.ci=${JOB_URL} sonar:sonar`

Comment: Is there a list of supported link types somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You can add `<ciManagement>` to the `pom.xml` file `.

Example:

```
<ciManagement>
    <system>travis</system>
    <url>https://travis-ci.org/your-project</url>
</ciManagement>
```

See [Maven POM Reference](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html).

---

You can also add information about:

- issue tracking system (`<issueManagement>`)
- sources hosting (`<scm>`)